# Como criar uma página que possua informações diferentes para cada tipo de usuário?

Tags: php, html

é minha primeira pergunta aqui no Stack overflow.
Bom, gostaria de saber como estruturaria uma página em php para exibir informações diferentes para usuários diferentes, pois não quero possuir mais de uma página para cada tipo de usuário.

Por exemplo, supondo que possua dois tipos de usuários, Administrador e Cliente, gostaria que para administrador exibisse, uma informação X e para Cliente uma informação Y.
Informações adicionais: tenho na Super Global $_SESSION o tipo do usuário.

Atenciosamente,
Ericks Rodrigues.

Comment: Você está usando alguma base de dados ? Qual ? Att, Tao Pai Pai.

Comment: Estou utilizando PDO para acessar um banco mysql, já estou manipulando as informações e já adquiro os dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == 1) { ?>
    <p>informação do usurário tipo 1</p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>exibe informações do usuário 2</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Ou

```
if ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == 1) {
    \\ exibe informações do usuário 1
} elseif ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == 2) {
    \\ exibe informações do usuário 2
} else {
    \\ exibe informações comum a todos
}
```

Se esta não for isto que deseja, adicione mais informações em sua pergunta.

Comment: olá marcusagm , eu entendo a questão do if, porém gostaria de uma estrutura não somente para um ou dois dados, gostaria de carregar páginas quase que completamente diferentes (como se fossem duas páginas diferentes na mesma). gostaria da melhor forma para utilizar um código html para cada condição.

Comment: Se vc quer um só arquivo para exibir o dados, vc vai ter que testar sempre que precisar exibir uma informação que for restrita. Se for muitas informações diferenciadas, não tem o pq de unificar em um arquivo só, isso apenas dificultaria a manutenção.

Comment: na verdade não preciso que sejam completamente diferentes, na minha aplicação apenas mostrar uns links para usuários tipo 1 e outros para usuários tipo 2, o objetivo da pergunta é saber como posso usar de forma mais apropriada os IFs para definir qual html será executado, pois a única forma que conheço para inserir html dentro de php é utilizando o echo.

Comment: Alterei a resposta da primeira forma com a solução

Comment: Ok, não sabia que poderia utilizar dessa forma ^^, muito obrigado marcusagm!

Comment: Nada Ericks ;) depois tenta melhorar um pouco sua pergunta é título, pode ser útil para outras pessoas. Coloca algo especifico como "usando ifs no meio de HTML sem usar echo"